# Keys are not unique for a python dictionary!

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

A stupid newbie question here
For a python dictionary q `len(set(q.keys())) != len(q.keys())`. Is that even possible?

Comment: can you post the dictionary for which this happens?

Comment: That is, in fact, not possible.

Comment: It is quite large and I can't reproduce the problem on small hand-made dictionary :( Key is a tuple of two variables: one is my custom class with __hash__ function I wrote myself, another one is integer.

Comment: @user it's possible that you're getting overflow errors. What are the values for `len(q.keys())` and `len(set(q.keys()))`?

Comment: `In [131]: len(s.q.keys())
Out[131]: 99

In [132]: len(set(s.q.keys()))
Out[132]: 9`

Comment: A guess: in Python a mutable object cannot be hashable.  It is possible to overcome this restriction, but that can result in weird hash table behaviors like what you observe.  (True not only in Python, but Python makes this explicit somewhere in documentation).

Comment: Overflow shouldn't be the case. And this shouldn't happen, except if `__hash__` is flawed and/or you don't have `__eq__`/`__ne__` overloaded.

Comment: Can you post the code for your own `__hash__` method and the class it defined in? It is likely that the problem is there

Comment: sure the objects are mutable, but `In [152]: len(set([hash(x) for x in s.q.keys()]))
Out[152]: 9

In [153]: len([hash(x) for x in s.q.keys()])
Out[153]: 99
`

Comment: I'm not very good with a markup here yet, I do apologise about that `    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self.board.flatten()))
` - the hash function of interest. self.board is a numpy array

Comment: You can post the code by editing your question. Did you overload `__eq__` or `__cmp__` as well? See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__hash__#object.__hash__ for more info on the subject

Comment: Oh sorry I think I found the problem. `__ne__` wasn't overloaded. Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 17):

This can happen if you violate a requirement of `dict`, and change its hash.

When an object is used in a `dict`, its hash value must not change, and its equality to other objects must not change.  Other properties *may* change, as long as they don't affect how it appears to the dict.

(This does *not* mean that a hash value is never allowed to change.  That's a common misconception.  Hash values themselves may change.  It's only `dict` which requires that key hashes be immutable, not `__hash__` itself.)

The following code adds an object to a dict, then changes its hash out from under the dict.  `q[a] = 2` then adds `a` as a new key in the dict, even though it's already present; since the hash value changed, the dict doesn't find the old value.  This reproduces the peculiarity you saw.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, h):
        self.h = h
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.h

a = Test(1)
q = {}
q[a] = 1
a.h = 2
q[a] = 2

print q

# True:
print len(set(q.keys())) != len(q.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying code for dictionaries and sets is substantially the same, so you can usually expect that `len(set(d.keys()) == len(d.keys())` is an invariant.

That said, both sets and dicts depend on __eq__ and __hash__ to identify unique values and to organize them for efficient search.  So, if those return inconsistent results (or violate the rule that "a==b implies hash(a)==hash(b)", then there is no way to enforce the invariant:

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> class A():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return bool(randrange(2))
    def __hash__(self):
        return randrange(8)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '|%d|' % self.x


>>> s = [A(i) for i in range(100)]
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(s)
>>> len(d.keys())
29
>>> len(set(d.keys()))
12
```